# Not understanding setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am reading a project that I have to work and do additional work on, but I don't understand some interval trickery that has been done and not explained by the previous person. That's the code:

```
var intervalId;
var intervalIdtwo;

 $(document).on('click', 'li.mention-individuals', function() {

                clearInterval(loadTimer);
                var otheridFromSearch = $(this).data('profileid');
                var searchImage = $(this).find('img.search-image').attr('src');
                var searchName = $(this).find('.mention-name').text();
                $('.users-right-pro-pic img').attr('src', searchImage);
                $('.users-right-pro-name').text(searchName);
                $('.user-info').attr("data-otherid", otheridFromSearch);
                xyz(useridd, otheridFromSearch, abc);

                $.post('http://localhost/facebook/core/ajax/message.php', {
                    showmsg: otheridFromSearch,
                    yourid: useridForAjax
                }, function(data) {
                    $('.msg-box').html(data);
                    $('.user-show').empty();
                    $('.top-msg-user-photo img').attr('src', searchImage);
                    $('.top-msg-user-name').text(searchName);
                    scrollItself();
                })

                if (!intervalId) {
                    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                        loadMessageFromSearch(useridForAjax, otheridFromSearch);
                    }, 1000);
                    clearInterval(intervalIdtwo);
                    intervalIdtwo = null;
                } else if (!intervalIdtwo) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    intervalId = null;
                    intervalIdtwo = setInterval(function() {
                        loadMessageFromSearch(useridForAjax, otheridFromSearch);
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    alert('Nothing found');
                }

            })

function loadMessageFromSearch(useridForAjax, otheridFromSearch) {
                var pastDataCount = $('.past-data-count').data('datacount'); //if no new data, the old messages will be shown 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/facebook/core/ajax/message.php",
                    data: {
                        showmsg: otheridFromSearch,
                        yourid: useridForAjax
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.msg-box').html(data);
                    }
                })

                $.post('http://localhost/facebook/core/ajax/message.php', {
                    dataCount: otheridFromSearch,
                    profileid: useridForAjax
                }, function(data) {
                    if (pastDataCount == data) {
                        console.log('data is same');
                    } else {
                        scrollItself();
                        console.log('data is not same');
                    }
                })
            }
```

I generally get the code, but the Ifs section with the IntervalId and IntervalIdTwo - I have no clue what it does. Any tips or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's trickery at all. Looks like redundant spaghetti logic to me that could be consolidated into one code block instead of two making it clearer to read and understand it's intent

Comment: In all honesty, going line by line I just don't understand very much why he/she has done that. Basically he/she calls to check if the data is the same every 1 second. Why was intervalIdTwo even needed?

Comment: My take is they wanted to start a new interval each click. That could easily be done using one variable and simply clearing it before starting new one. Looks ugly to me

Comment: I sometimes feel blind when looking at someone else's code. What you said makes perfect sense. Thanks! I usually don't write code like that, I mean even Intervals are new to me, thus I didn't catch it myself. But I agree, a classic case of useless code.

Comment: Yes... I think "useless code" sums it up correctly

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, the `setInterval` function is simple: it takes a function and a number `n` and calls the function (at most) every `n` milliseconds. It also returns a "handle" that allows you to cancel the repeated invocations by calling `clearInterval` with the handle.

For instance, here is a function that logs a string to the console:

```
function sayHello() {
  console.log('hello!');
}
```

We can call it every second (1000 milliseconds) like so:

```
setInterval(sayHello, 1000);
```

(You can even try it out in your browser's dev. tools right now! It should print `'hello!'` every second)

What if we want to stop printing `'hello!'`? If we "hold onto" the return value, we can cancel the repeated invocations:

```
const handle = setInterval(sayHello, 1000);
```

(If you're curious, try printing `handle`!)

To cancel the process, call the `clearInterval` function with the handle:

```
clearInterval(handle);
```

A couple of notes:

1. In a lot of cases, it is a pain to define a separate function like `sayHello`, so we would instead use an "anonymous function", like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('hello!');
}, 1000);

// or

setInterval(() => console.log('hello!'), 1000);
```

This underscores the fact that `setInterval` is a *higher-order function*: it takes another function as one of its arguments. This can take some getting used to, but with practice it becomes second nature.

2. Depending on how "busy" your browser is, the invocations may not take place at exactly the interval you specify. The delay may be *longer* than the number you provide, but never *shorter* (see 3. below for why).
3. if you really want to grok `setInterval` you will need an understanding of JavaScript's [concurrency model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).